# Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, jpa-2.1

I have one lawyer table which is having id(int) as a primary key and Country table having country_code(String ) as a primary key. I want to create third table using @JoinTable annotation in hibernate with two foreign key in it. But when I run it following error is coming. Not sure how to map one string and one int as foreign keys in third table.

```
Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.test.common.entities.Country.lawyer
```

This is my code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lawyer")
public class Lawyer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "lawyer_batch_no")
    private int lawyerbatchNo;

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Country.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(name = "lawyer_cscd", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "lawyer_batch_no", referencedColumnName = "lawyer_batch_no") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "country_code", referencedColumnName = "country_code") })
    private Country country;

getter setter...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
public class Country {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "country_code")
    protected String country_code;

    @Column(name = "abbreviation")
    protected String abbreviation;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    protected String name;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "country")
    protected Set<State> state = new HashSet<State>();

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Lawyer.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinTable(name = "lawyer_cscd", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "country_code", referencedColumnName = "country_code") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "lawyer_batch_no", referencedColumnName = "lawyer_batch_no") })
    private Lawyer lawyer;

getter setter....
}
```

Comment: The error indicates that `private Lawyer lawyer;` needs to be a collection as it's a oneToMany relationship

Comment: @baao thanks for indication that's a foolish mistake from my side thanks for helping

Answer (score 3):

The error indicates that `private Lawyer lawyer` needs to be a collection as it's a `@OneToMany` relationship. In the `Country` class, the last relationship should be

```
@OneToMany(targetEntity = Lawyer.class, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinTable(name = "lawyer_cscd", joinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "country_code", referencedColumnName = "country_code") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
    @JoinColumn(name = "lawyer_batch_no", referencedColumnName = "lawyer_batch_no") })
private Set<Lawyer> lawyer;
// or a Collection/List/etc.
```

Comment: I have one more question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40829022/field-district-code-doesnt-have-a-default-value?noredirect=1#comment68876061_40829022 I am getting error can you please look into it and let me know

Comment: in my case, referencedColumnName wasn't needed.